# Display Updated Time Ago Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking to display a "Blog updated X days ago" style message on my Wordpress site, I've tried the below code, but it's throwing an error.

```
                <?php 
                    $posted = get_the_time('U');
                    $newest = $wpdb->get_row("select post_modified from $wpdb->posts 
                    where post_type in ('page', 'post') and post_status = 'publish' order by post_modified desc");
                    echo mysql2date('m/d/Y',$newest->post_modified);
                    echo human_time_diff( strtotime( $newest ), current_time( 'timestamp', 1 ) );
                ?>
```

> Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string

Any help would be great!

Comment: If you `var_dump($newest)` before the `human_time_diff` what do you get? The error is pretty straightforward. [strtotime manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: ```object(stdClass)[1327]
  public 'post_modified' => string '2021-06-08 13:50:05' (length=19)```

Comment: Yeah, it's an Object, just change it to `$newest->post_modified`

Comment: Epic, thank you. If you want to write an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are passing something other than a string to [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

From the `var_dump` of `$newest` you are passing an Object.

```
object(stdClass)[1327]   
      public 'post_modified' => string '2021-06-08 13:50:05' (length=19)
```

You can grab the `post_modified` property - since that is a string.

Update this line:

```
    // Updates $newest to $newest->post_modified
    echo human_time_diff( strtotime( $newest->post_modified ), current_time( 'timestamp', 1 )  );
```